# Suppose $G$ is a finite group. What can we say about the representations (matrices) corresponding to elements of $G$?

Tags: representation-theory

$G$ is finite and $\rho: G \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a group representation of $G$.

What I would like to know is what do the properties of $G$ (it being finite) tell us about the matrices corresponding to group elements $\rho(g)$?  What can we conclude?  For example, what can we say about diagonalizability and why?

Answer (score 4):

Each such $\rho(g)$ is diagonalisable and its eigenvalues are roots of unity. If $g^n=1\in G$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, then $X^n=I$ for $X=\rho(g)$.
As the polynomial $x^n-1$ has distinct roots over $\Bbb C$ then
$X$ is diagonalisable, and its eigenvalues are $n$-th roots of unity.

Conversely, any solution of $X^n=I$ occurs as $\rho(g)$ for
some representation of the cyclic group $C_n$.

Comment: Note that infinite groups can have representations where the matrices are not diagonalizable.  For example, the group $\mathbb{Z}$ has a representation $\rho(n) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and this matrix is diagonalizable only for $n=0$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Obviously any invertible matrix can arise in a representation of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

Since every representation $ \rho: G\to GL(n,\mathbb C)$ can be taken to be unitary, i.e., there exists an $M\in GL(n,\mathbb C)$ for all $g\in G$, such that $M^{-1}\rho(g)M\in U_n=\{P\in GL(n,\mathbb C)|P^\ast P=I_n\}$ where $P^\ast$ is the complex conjugate of $P$.

The spectral theorem tells us that every unitary matrix is diagonalizable with all the eigenvalues having absolute value one.

In particular, $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable.